# How to format ISO strings without milliseconds?

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs

I have date-time strings in different ISO formats which I have to compare for equality. I can only use the moment.js library for working with dates.

```
Example 1 - 2022-10-15T20:00:00Z
Example 2 - 2022-10-15T20:00:00.0459273Z
```

I want to convert both date-time strings to the format seen in example 1 and then compare them as strings. How do I convert the strings with moment.js? Is there a way to specify an ISO format which looks like example 1, or do I have to use string replacement to make date-time strings comparable. I see that `moment(timeString).toISOString()` does not work for this because it gives a time format like `2016-11-22T17:00:00.000Z` which is not like example 1.

Comment: Why not use the [compare methods](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/) that Moment.js provides and pass the precision that you want to use (second parameter)? `moment(example1).isSame(moment(example2), "second") //=> true` This code compares year, month, day, hour, minute, and second.

Comment: What's the input? A string or a momentjs object? If it's a string, I would use string replace (`'2022-10-15T20:00:00.0459273Z'.replace(/\.\d+/, '')`). There's no reason to involve momentjs. If it's a momentjs object, I would use momentjs comparison (see previous comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. We can specify a format like this:

```
moment(someDateString).format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss[Z]')
```

The square brackets escape characters (such as YYYY, MM etc.) in format strings. Then perform a string comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You can try formatting the ISO string returned from moment(timeString).toISOString() to the example 1 format:

```js
console.log("2016-11-22T17:00:00.000Z".split('.')[0]+"Z")
```